# $f''$ bounded implies $f'$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that $f''$ exists on $[0,1]$ and that $f(0)=0=f(1)$. Suppose also that $|f''(x)|\le K$ for $x\in(0,1)$. Prove that $|f'(1/2)|\le K/4$ and that $|f'(x)|\le K/2$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

The mean-value theorem might help, but I can't see how.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424553/if-f-prime-prime-is-bounded-then-f-prime-is-bounded-by-half-of-the-const/424592) for the second part.

Comment: [This problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418996/integral-inequality-with-derivative/419027#419027)  may offer some ideas as well.

Comment: Ok I think I get the idea. I'll write up an answer for the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f'\left(\dfrac12\right)>K/4$ and $f\left(\dfrac12\right)>0$ (other cases are handled similarly.)

For $\dfrac12<t<1$ we have $f'(t)=f'\left(\dfrac12\right)+\int_{\frac12}^{t}f''(x)dx>\dfrac{K}{4}+\int_{\frac12}^{t}-Kdx = \dfrac{3K}{4}-Kt$.

Then $f(1)=f\left(\dfrac12\right)+\int_{\frac12}^{1}f'(x)dx > 0 + \int_{\frac12}^1\left(\dfrac{K}{4}-K\left(t-\dfrac12\right)\right)dt=0$, a contradiction.